# Login website --> give credentials like key press from console

Tags: powershell, authentication, web, key

I am testing a web page, and want to make a script to login in the website automatically.

My script goes as follows:

```
$username = 'username'
$password = 'password'

$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("url")

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -seconds 1; }

$usernamefield = $ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[0]
$usernamefield.value = $username

$passwordfield = $ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[1]
$passwordfield.value = $password

$Link = $ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input") |
        Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "button"}
$Link.Click()
```

I have to search the tag names that way because the id is randomized on each time.

My problem here is that I can not click on the Login button, because somehow the website expects credentials to be passed like a key press (I manage to complete the credential fields, but the page does not recognize it, as if they were empty). How can I achieve this, or where can I learn doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to send a keystroke, you could use the SendKeys function.
I've used this is scripts before, but have found it more reliable if you incorporate PSCX's `Set-ForegroundWindow` cmdlet as well to make sure your browser or app is the currently focused application:

```
 $Shell = New-Object -COM “WScript.Shell”
 $Shell.SendKeys(“F15”)
```

Would send a F15 keystroke.

Hope that gives you a place to start from.

There's another 3rd party module out in the wild called WASP that you could install.

https://wasp.codeplex.com/

Also, Adam Driscoll wrote a Powershell module that wraps Selenium's C# WebDriver:

https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell